# Values Passed Data to apex controller returning Null

Tags: apex, aura

I am creating a code that is supposed to Saved data given by the user, however the data that I pass to apex is null, I cannot get why.

here is my js:

```
handleSave(){
        console.log("Saving...")
        this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saving...'
        this.updatedData['Id'] = this.recordData.Id
        console.log(this.updatedData)
        
        UW_SavedData({records : this.updatedData}).then(() => {
            console.log('then trigered')
            this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved';
            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title : 'Success',
                    message : `Records saved succesfully!`,
                    variant : 'success',
                }),
            )
            this.isEdited = false;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
            //console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
            }, 3000);
        }); 

    }
```

here for example in my console.log(this.updatedData), it prints to my console:
`{UW_occupency_rate__c: "45", Id: "00Q2600000DVMLeEAP"}`

my apex looks like that:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void UW_SavedData(Lead records){
    system.debug('test');
    system.debug(records);
    if(records != null){
        system.debug(records);
        string currentId = records.Id;
        Lead Prop = [SELECT Id, UW_occupency_rate__c, UW_otherRevenue__c, UW_roomCostOfSales__c, UW_OtherCostOfSales__c,
                            UW_OperatingCost__c, UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c, UW_taxCost__c, UW_MaxRent__c
                            FROM Lead WHERE Id = :currentId];   
        //Prop.UW_occupency_rate__c = record.UW_occupency_rate__c;
        //Prop.UW_otherRevenue__c = record.UW_otherRevenue__c;
        //Prop.UW_roomCostOfSales__c = record.UW_roomCostOfSales__c;
        //Prop.UW_OtherCostOfSales__c = record.UW_OtherCostOfSales__c;
        //Prop.UW_OperatingCost__c = record.UW_OperatingCost__c;
        //Prop.UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c = record.UW_LabourAndBenefitCost__c;
        //Prop.UW_taxCost__c = record.UW_taxCost__c;
        //Prop.UW_MaxRent__c = record.UW_MaxRent__c;
        //update Prop;
        
        }     
    }
```

and here my system debug print my
test ==> so the apex class is triggered but  system.debug(records) return Null

What am I doing wrong ? I should be able to see my data ..
thx you

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [blog](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2019/04/08/passing-sobject-record-from-lwc-to-custom-apex-methods-for-dml-operations/) you need to either pass the object to the apex as object and not as sobject, or you need to add the `{'sobjectType':'Contact'}`.